# React apollo - How to pass props to Query and access it in child

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Currently we are using the variables to pass the props which are required in the child.

```
<Query
        variables={{
          queryVar1: 'a',
          queryVar3: 'a',
          props1: this.props.prop1,
          props2: this.props.prop1,
        }}
        query={SOMEQUERY}
        fetchPolicy="network-only"
      >
        { myComp }
      </Query>
```

But this is making the code cluttered. how else we can pass the props from parent to child.

Answer (score 0):

You can try context api or you can create your own higher order function to share params (e.g. withXParams)